# Получить дату в определенном формате

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно в программе на C# получить значение текущей даты в формате "год-месяц-день время" (как предусматривает тип DATETIME в MySql). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Смотрите на [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Подробно о [форматировании дат и времени](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/19.2.php)

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: Если нужен **точный** формат, я бы использовал `now.ToString(..., CultureInfo.InvatiantCulture)`. Иначе результат может зависеть от текущей локали, а это скорее всего для MySql не подходит.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;
      Console.WriteLine(thisDay.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine(thisDay.ToString("d"));
      Console.WriteLine(thisDay.ToString("D"));
      Console.WriteLine(thisDay.ToString("g"));
   }
}
```