# Заменить символы двоеточия или точки в формате времени на заданное слово

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Подскажите, можно ли во времени, например: 01:00:05 типа `DateTime` или `TimeSpan` заменить двоеточия на сокращения ч, мин или сек и при этом убрать нули до первого значащего числа?
Возможно ли это сделать функциями .net, дабы не писать свой парсер?

Вот что это означает: например у нас есть строка 00:01:00, на экране увидим 1m00s. Я бы хотел чтобы было 1мин00сек

Вот пример как вместо двоеточия использовать другие символы h, m или s:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(00, 01, 00);
string s = ts.ToString(@"d\d\h\hmm\mss\s").TrimStart(' ', 'd', 'h', 'm', 's', '0');
```

Comment: @Andrew вы имеете ввиду отдельно вытянуть дни, часы и т.д. и сформировать строку на их основе?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получить дату в определенном формате](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681424/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: Если не сработает вытягивание такое из таймспана(хотя, уверен, что сработает), то конвертони в DateTime и тогда переводи в строку.

Comment: @Andrew не думаю, что это дубликат вопроса. То что вы указали, выводит дату в определённом формате, но время там везде через двоеточие. Мне же хочется изменить именно время

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вроде должно быть все понятно по коду

```
var a = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy лет MM месяцев dd  дней hh часов mm минут ss секунд");
```

Результат:

> 2018 лет 12 месяцев 20  дней 04 часов 51 минут 21 секунд

- MM - Месяц с предшествующим нулем
- M - просто месяц без нулей
- dd - с ну нулем
- d - без нулей
- yyyy - 4-символьный год
- yy - 2-хсимвольный год
- HH - 24часовый формат часов с предшествующим нулем
- H - 24часовый формат без предшествующим нуля
- hh - 12часовый формат часов с предшествующим нулем
- h - 12часовый формат часов без нуля
- mm - минут с предшествующим нулем
- m - без нуля
- ss - секунды с предшествующим нулем
- s - секунды без предшествующего нуля.

.

дальше просто логика обрезания начала строки.

То есть тебе нужно что-то вроде метода:

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{

    public static string ToCustomDateStr(this DateTime dt)
    {
        string str;

        if (dt.Hour != 0)
        {
            str = dt.ToString("Hчас mмин sсек");
        }
        else
        {
            str = dt.ToString("mмин sсек");
        }

        return str;
    }

}
```

и использование:

```
var a = DateTime.Now.ToCustomDateStr();
```

результат будет...

> 17час 56мин 36сек

или

> 56мин 36сек

или

> 6час 56мин 36сек

Comment: я долго пытался вникнуть в вопрос и, как мне кажется, автор хочет немного другое. есть строка "00:01:00", которую надо преобразоваеть с в 1мин 0сек. т.е. если нет часов - убрать их, если нет минут - убрать их.

Comment: Я могу перефразировать вопрос. Мне он показался понятным)

Comment: @morphey83 прав

Comment: а, тогда сейчас исправлю ответ и сделаю откат

Comment: Подправил немного вопрос, сделал уточнения. Надеюсь стало понятнее)

Comment: актувализировал ответ

Answer (score 1):

Если брать за основу, что начальная строка не содержит ошибок, то:

```
var sep = new [] {"ч","мин","сек"};
var t = string.Join(" ", "03:01:00"
    .Split(':')
    .Select((s, i) => s == "00" ? string.Empty : $"{int.Parse(s)}{sep[i]}")
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Для типа TimeSpan придумал вот такой конвертер (если не хочется использовать DateTime. В моём случае работать с DateTime мне было не удобно):

```
public static string ToCustomDateStr(TimeSpan ts)
        {
            string str;
            string parseString = ts.ToString(@"d\.h\:m\:s").TrimStart(' ', 'd', 'h', 'm', 's', '0', '.', ':');
            string[] duration = parseString.Split('.', ':');

            if (duration.Length == 1)
                str = ts.Seconds.ToString() + "sec";
            else if (duration.Length == 2)
                str = ts.Minutes.ToString() + "min " + ts.Seconds.ToString() + "sec";
            else if (duration.Length == 3)
                str = ts.Hours.ToString() + "h " + ts.Minutes.ToString() + "min " + ts.Seconds.ToString() + "sec";
            else if (duration.Length == 4)
                str = ts.Days.ToString() + "d " + ts.Hours.ToString() + "h " + ts.Minutes.ToString() + "min " + ts.Seconds.ToString() + "sec";
            else
                str = string.Empty;

            return str;    
        }
```

Я делаю строку вида `день.часы:минуты:секунды`, затем разбиваю её и формирую новую в зависимости от того, сколько данных получилось после разбиения.