# Правильно ли я сделал таймер?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

```
public float hour, min, sec;

void Update(){

     TimerStart();
}
void TimerStart()
    {
        if (hour >= 0)
        {
            sec -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (sec < 0)
            {
                sec = 59;
                min--;
            }
            if (min < 0)
            {
                min = 59;
                hour--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Часы, минуты и секунды задаю с инспектора. Мне не нужен сверхточный таймер, но принцип правильный? А может есть какие-нибудь более легкие способы, встроенные функции и т.д.?

Comment: Погуглите в сторону TimeSpan

Comment: Лично мне интересно для начала для чего этот таймер нужен. В зависимости от ответа я смогу ответить про то каким путем лучше идти)

Comment: @Andrew когда прошел например текущий бонусный уровень, то повторно можно играть только через, нуу, 48 часов. Таймер срабатывает, при выходе из игры сохраняет в PlayerPrefs часы, минуты, секунды, при входе в игру вычитывает время отсутствия с таймера. Еще возможно будут ивенты, отдельный таймер будет на сервере, типа будет иконка где показано время начала слеующего турнира и там таймер тикает

Comment: Человек правильно написал о TimeSpan, используйте лучше его.

Comment: @JediMan4ik да, я для второго таймера тот использовал

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> @Andrew когда прошел например: текущий бонусный уровень, то повторно можно играть только через, нуу, 48 часов. Таймер срабатывает, при выходе из игры сохраняет в PlayerPrefs часы, минуты, секунды, при входе в игру вычитывает время отсутствия с таймера.

Мои подозрения оправдались :)

В даном конкретном случае таймер не нужен ВОВСЕ. Все что тебе нужно -- запомнить время когда можно будет делать следующую итерацию. В даном случае пусть будет вызов метода `BonusGame()`

будет как-то так:

```
public void BonusGame()
{ 
    if( DateTime.Now > PlayerPrefsNextBonusGameTime)
    { 
        //some bonus Game Logic
    }
}
```

а что бы показать время оставшийся до возможной игры в бонусную игру, то нужно что-то вроде:

```
public TimeSpan TimeLeftToBonusGame {
    get { 
        return DateTime.Now - PlayerPrefsNextBonusGameTime ;
    }
}
```

где PlayerPrefsNextBonusGameTime -- DateTime.

все писалось исключительно в рамках псевдокода и может не сработать при копировании, но тут главное понять подход.

Comment: Всё, я вас понял)

Comment: txt.text = string.Format("{0}", TimeLeftToBonusGame); как отформатировать, чтобы секундах показывал в int, т.е 2 целые цифры и чтоб минуса не было спереди?

Comment: И еще, люди могут обмануть таймер, поменяй время на телефоне (пк)?

Comment: так адекватно будет? Просто умножил всё на -1: txt.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", TimeLeftToBonusGame.Hours*(-1), TimeLeftToBonusGame.Minutes * (-1), TimeLeftToBonusGame.Seconds*(-1) );

Comment: не нужно форматировать никак. Сравнивай время как DateTime. А еще почитай про форматирование времени. Например вот здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/923406/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал приватное поле `private float secondsLeft`, в методе `Start` инициализировал его как `secondsLeft = hour*60*60 + min*60 + sec` и в методе `Update` добавил бы строки

```
secondsLeft -= Time.deltaTime
if (secondsLeft <= 0)
{
    //do smth
}
```

Полностью:

```
public float hour, min, sec;
private float secondsLeft;

void Start()
{
    secondsLeft = hour*60*60 + min*60 + sec;
}

void Update()
{
    secondsLeft -= Time.deltaTime
    if (secondsLeft <= 0)
    {
        //do smth
    }
}
```

Либо использовать корутины (про это советую почитать отдельно, очень полезная вещь). Приведу просто пример:

```
public float hour, min, sec;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Timer(hour*60*60 + min*60 + sec));
}

private IEnumerator Timer(float secondsToWait)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(secondsToWait);
    //do smth after timer
    yield return null
}
```

Comment: да, мне нравится первый вариант, но наглядно надо показывать сколько часов, минут, секунд осталось. Так наверное будет только в секундах показывать

Answer (score 1):

ты просто запомнил абсолютное время когда уже можно войти в бонусную игру
дальше в отдельном `MyBonusTimeHandler:MonoBehaviour` используй `Invoke('название метода который активирует возможность',DateTime.Now - PlayerPrefsNextBonusGameTime);` в методе `Start()`
движек сам вызовет тот метод через указанное время
время в `float` если я ошибся выше, не помню про перегрузки

Comment: IMHO, тут полезные способы с примерами: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056471/how-make-the-script-wait-sleep-in-a-simple-way-in-unity

Comment: Ваш ответ не останется незамеченным, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Зачем извращаться и писать свой таймер, когда в C# есть `TimeSpan` ?

Просто вызываете [`TimeSpan.Add`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timespan.add?view=netframework-4.7.2) к уже имеющемуся времени и добавляете необходимое время.

Хотите на экран выводить? Есть множество форматов в `ToString()`.